# firebase-dynamic-links - [33353:495188] 8.5.0[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023001]Deep Link does not contain valid required params."match_message"="No pre

Tags: objective-c, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have followed the below steps.

- create project on firebase.
- add iOS app with below details
- bundle ID.
- App id.
- team is.
- added url schema in Xcode - bundle ID and associated domain - (applinks: suddynamic.page.link)
- created domain on dynamic links. -https://suddynamic.page.link
- add new dynamic links like. - short link - https://suddynamic.page.link/test1 with - deep link - https://www.example.com/data?hello=world&foo=bar & Link link like - .

below are the attached image - FYI

Getting below error -

FirebaseDemo[33353:495188] 8.5.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023001] Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params
"match_message" = "No pre-install link matched for this device.";
"request_ip_version" = "IP_V6";

I will appreciate your early reply...

Comment: FirebaseDemo[33353:495188] 8.5.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023001] Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
    "match_message" = "No pre-install link matched for this device.";
    "request_ip_version" = "IP_V6";
}
Getting this error

Comment: Possibly a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299784/firebase-dynamic-links-do-not-survive-app-install-on-ios-11-3-1